# IntelliJ: Is there an Intention Action to convert old style Log4J calls to new style SLF4J calls?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, slf4j, intellij-14

I am working on a project with legacy code that had used Log4J in the past, and now uses SLF4J. Most of the old style Log4J logging statements remain, and I convert the log statements slowly to the new SLF4J style as I come across them.

I've just realised that pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when in the old style log statements gives me the following options (unfortunately I cannot upload a screenshot):

- Copy String concatenation text to the clipboard
- Inject language or reference
- Replace '+' with 'String.format()'
- Replace '+' with 'StringBuilder.append()'
- Replace '+' with 'java.test.MessageFormat.format()'

The option `Replace '+' with 'String.format()'` is very close to what I need, although I don't need the `String.format(` bit.

**Is there something that would give me an Intention Action of: `Replace Log4J style log statement with SLF4J style log statement`?**

As an example of old logging style (e.g. Log4J), I mean:

```
LOGGER.debug("User " + user.getUserId() + " has performed a search with the criteria " + dto);
```

And by new style I mean:

```
LOGGER.debug("User {} has performed a search with the criteria {}", user.getUserId(), dto);
```

Comment: Intellij has structural replace that might help you (but I have not used it enough to help you out more spefically here): https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html

Comment: @WimDeblauwe It certainly does help! Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried the *Java | Logging issues | Non-constant string concatenation as argument to logging call* inspection? It has a quickfix to automatically convert a string concatenation to a parameterized log message.

Comment: This suggestion to use an _Inspection_ is closer to an _Intention Action_ than _Structural Replace_. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, on intellij 2019.1 even afterturning the inspection on, I still dont see the quick Fix . any extra settings needs to be done

Comment: found the answer: quick fix a available on the log function rather than on the string itself.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Wim Deblauwe's comment about SSR I have discovered *Edit | Find | Structural Replace* and using the following to fix simple cases where two arguments are used in a logging statement:

Search template:

```
LOGGER.debug("$str1$" + $arg1$ + "$str2$" + $arg2$)
```

Replacement template:

```
LOGGER.debug("$str1${}$str2${}", $arg1$, $arg2$)
```

I doubt I am using the Structural Search and Replace feature to its maximum capability, and will have to do a few sweeps to get all the logging statements, but this is great progress. Thank you Wim.

Comment: useful for bulk issues